# Are C/C++ operator precedence & associativity rules ever violated?

Tags: c++, syntax, operators, operator-precedence, associativity

Are [operator precedence & associativity rules](http://cpp.operator-precedence.com/) ever violated in any C/C++ expression? 
If so, can you give an example?

Assume the claims of precedence and associativity rules are:

> Each operator has a given precedence level, and each precedence level has a given associativity. If a sub-expression is seen by two operators where they expect an operand, it belongs to the one with higher precedence. Ties are broken by associativity.

#### Edit: Background

The standard defines C/C++ expressions as a CFG, which is much more flexible than a precedence-based parser. For example, it would have been possible to give binary operators asymmetrical "precedence", which would have rendered *any* precedence table incorrect. However, it appears to me that the design of the grammar was constrained to uphold simple precedence rules. Here are some alleged "counterexamples" that I have come across:

#### 1)  `a?b,c:d` is not interpreted as `(a?b),(c:d)`

Some claim that the `?:` operator exhibits different precedence towards its middle operand than towards its other operands, because `a?b,c:d`, for example, is not interpreted as `(a?b),(c:d)`. However, neither `b` nor `c` occupies a position in which it appears to `?:` as its inner operand. By that reasoning `a[b+c]` should be interpreted as `(a[b)+(c])`, which is ludicrous.

#### 2)  `sizeof(int)*a` is interpreted as `(sizeof(int))*a` rather than `sizeof((int)(*a))`

... because C disallows an uparenthesized cast as sizeof's operator. However, both of these interpretations conform to precedence rules. The confusion comes from the `*` operator's ambiguity (Is it the binary or the unary operator?). Precedence tables are not meant to resolve operator ambiguities. They are, after all, not operator-*symbol*-precedence tables. So the *operator* precedence rules themselves are intact.

#### 3)  `a+b=c` results in syntax error, not semantic error

`a+b=c`, according to the standard, is invalid C *syntax*. If C had had a precedence-based parser, it would only have been caught at the *semantic* level. In C, it so happens that any expression that is not a *unary-expression* cannot be l-valued. These semantically doomed LHS expressions therefore do not need to be accommodated syntactically. It makes no difference to the language as a whole, and precedence tables needn't be in the business of predicting the syntacticness/symanticness of the error that is going to result from an expression.

Comment: Why do you ask?  The rules are supposed to be "cast in concrete", but there's always the possibility (though remote) of a compiler bug.  But far more often the rules are simply misinterpreted by the user.

Comment: @HotLicks - it's also possible that the "precedence rules" are wrong. The language definition doesn't talk about precedence.

Comment: What do you mean by, "the question is about the language, not the parser"? The syntax parser either correctly reflects the language specification, or else it's non-conforming. So any conforming syntax parser agrees with the language. What's "*the* parser", if not a conforming parser?

Comment: @HotLicks I agree. See the added background.

Comment: @SteveJessop *Syntax* parser. C takes some syntactic shorcuts that affect the syntax without affecting the language. I've removed that sentence, and added example 3.

Comment: I've never actually dug into the C/C++ grammar standard, but for Java I know the "ultimate authority" is the BNF grammar, not any tables.  Any tables you see (for Java, at least) are derived from the grammar, and different authors may derive them slightly differently.  This could lead to some apparent anomalies, if you look only at the tables.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes the C/C++ standard also uses a CFG to define syntax. People keep undermining the authority of the precedence table (which is *much* more convenient to refer to) by saying the things you say above. Now I want to see an example of such an anomaly.

Comment: @IsakduPreez -- I'm saying that, since the language is specified by the grammar, any precedence and associativity tables are derived, and different authors may therefore produce slightly different derivations.  I don't offhand know of any such differences, but they wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: @HotLicks The question is: Is it *possible* to derive a precedence table that is *never* incorrect?

Comment: Well, you finally asked the question you intended?  With footnotes, yes.  But it may well be (I've never tried) that (without footnotes) it's impossible to reduce the C++ standard rules to simple lists/tables of precedence and associativity, and cover all forms of all expressions.

Comment: @HotLicks Sorry for not wording it well originally. But note again, the question is not whether it is possible to reduce the C++ standard to lists/tables. The constraints imposed by precedence & associativity can be correct and underdetermined at the same time.

Comment: Certainly you can derive a table that's "never incorrect" if some of the entries are "*" for "underdetermined", or whatever weasel words you want.

Comment: @HotLicks The question here is quite simple, and it isn't asking whether the table can define the language.

Comment: Well, it may be "simple", but it's not clear.

Comment: @HotLicks What is unclear to you? The question describes the claims of a precedence table, links to one, and asks for falsification. At no point does the question ask whether the C/C++ expression grammar can be completely described by a table. Even a precedence parser uses knowledge outside the table to disambiguate operators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For one example, the usual precedence table says that `sizeof` and cast expressions have the same precedence. Both the table and the standard say that they associate right-to-left.

This simplification is fine when you're looking at, say, `*&foo`, which means the same as `*(&foo)`.

It might also suggest to you that `sizeof (int) 1` is legal C++ and that it means the same thing as `sizeof( (int) 1 )`. But it's not legal, because in fact `sizeof( type-id )` is a special thing of its own in the grammar. Its existence prevents `sizeof (int) 1` from being a `sizeof` expression whose operand is a cast-expression whose operand is `1`.

So I think you could say that the "sizeof ( *type-id* )" production in the C++ grammar is an exception to what the usual precedence/associativity tables say. They *do* accurately describe the "sizeof *unary-expression*" production.

Comment: +1 for finding something interesting! But as you suggest one could argue that the `sizeof` in `sizeof(int)` (like the `=` in `int a=0`) is not the operator that appears in the table. The operator precedence table is not a lexeme precedence table, after all. (It cannot even resolve *operator* ambiguities.)

Comment: @Isak: OK, but if the question is about the exact definition of what it means for a syntax to "obey precedence and associativity" then I don't think I'm interested in it. It is not possible to parse C expressions solely with a precedence parser following the rules in the table, that is clear. That's another way of saying that there are examples of C expressions whose parse isn't defined by the table. If they aren't "exceptions" then I don't think I understood the question.

Comment: It is clear that the `sizeof` in `sizeof(int)` is not an operator, because `int` can't be an operand. The precedence table is about *operators*. (Note also that my question is not whether the system of constraints imposed by the precedence table is underdetermined, but whether they are ever violated. I.e. whether the precedence table is truly a property of the language.)

Comment: @Isak: in that case, if the question is, "is it possible to make 1 or more true statements about the C++ grammar, which are phrased in terms of operator precedence and associativity?" then I'm pretty sure the answer is "yes". The article you link to gives an example of why there's FUD about these tables, though. MSDN lists `?:` on a precedence level of its own, above the assignment operators. The article points out that this is inaccurate with respect to `true ? x : y = 5`. If all else fails you can just leave out operators that could cause confusion and get an accurate but incomplete table.

Comment: Yes indeed, but see the 3rd and 4th sentences in my question. "*each* operator".

Comment: @Isak: But since you've cleverly defined that when `sizeof` doesn't follow precedence rules it's not an operator, you can probably deal with any such objections to anything you have to leave out. To the extent that C can be parsed in terms of operators with precedence and associativity, it can be parsed in those terms ;-) Alternatively you could say that `sizeof(int)` is a nullary operator (aka a value) from a family of similar, just like `(int)` is a unary operator from a family. Then add this "other `sizeof`" to the table with precedence and associativity "n/a".

Comment: Basically, AFAIK there are no grammar productions in C++ that amount to "associativity of operator X is right-to-left in some contexts but left-to-right in others". So to the extent that X "is" an operator, its associativity is consistent, noting for example that `++` is two unrelated operators. You'd have to look closely at `?:`, since having three operands I believe the definition of "precedence" and "associativity" might cover corner cases that don't occur for binary operators. But since there's only one ternary operator, there's only one correct way to frame the definitions, no exceptions.

Comment: I don't think "nullary operators" (such as sizeof(int), 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc.) want to be in the *precedence* table because they don't have any operands to fight over.

Comment: @Isak: sure, I'm just pointing out that there's more than one way to frame this. *If* you want an entry in the table "for each operator", *then* you're still free to choose whether to call `sizeof(int)` an operator or not.

Comment: If you want to leave it out of the table, then you're constrained to say it's not an operator. Either way you're enlarging on the standard's fairly ad hoc approach to what is and is not an operator: it lists "sizeof (type-id)" as a production under "unary operators", it doesn't list either kind of `sizeof` as a *unary-operator*, and in 5.3.3/1, C++03 explicitly states that `(int)` is the operand of `sizeof` in `sizeof(int)`, even though above you define that it is not an operand. Basically, you have to take some liberties with the terminology in the standard to produce that table.

Comment: Good point! The answer to my question as it stands still seems to be that there are no exceptions, since `(int)` is not a sub-*expression* of `sizeof(int)`. Good wording to compensate for the standard's bad wording :)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether the "rules" are correct. The language definition doesn't talk about precedence, so the precedence tables you see in various places may or may not reflect what the language definition actually requires.

Comment: Given the way the language is defined, does a precedence table exist that in no way contradicts the standard? See the added background.

Comment: @IsakduPreez - I've heard that precedence really doesn't capture the true rules, but I haven't looked into it. The standard is clear enough for me, without introducing unofficial reformulations.

Comment: A *lot* of redundant information goes into the definition of a CFG, if it is already known to be constrained by precedence rules. For most it would be a nightmare if all the binary operators could have different glue on each side. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Until someone can find a counterexample, I'm going to put forward this as the default answer:

No, C/C++ precedence and associativity rules are never violated.